# Ring and Pole - Box2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, cocos2d-x

How I can make a b2Body in box2d so that it could form a ring which does not collide from the center just like a ring. like when we flick the object and there's another body (like pole), the pole can go inside from the ring.

like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a joint of two circle bodies like this

```
o o  ->

          ||
          ||
         o||o
          ||
```

Comment: You can also put two fixtures on one rigid body.

Answer (score 0):

What first comes to mind is to invert the pole, i.e the pole itself is just a hole and the space around it is boxes. Then place an inverted image over it (that looks like a pole), then have the rings fall into the hole. Just a matter of fooling the eye.